# How to prove a variety is not closed (in a certain larger one)?

Tags: algebraic-groups

Here is the problem:

> Show by example that the subgroup of an algebraic group generated by two non-irreducible closed subsets need not be closed.

and a hint is given:

> Use the cyclic subgroups of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ generated by $\begin{pmatrix}
>  1 & 0 \\ 
>  0 & -1 
> \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
>  1 & 1 \\ 
>  0 & -1 
> \end{pmatrix}$.

Now, let $G_1 = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} \} $ and $G_2 = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\ 
 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} \}$ (the cyclic subgroups generated by $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 
 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 \\ 
 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$
). Both are closed and non-irreducible subsets (subgroups). The subgroup generated by $G_1$ and $G_2$ is $G = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & n_1 \\ 
 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & n_2 \\ 
 0 & -1 
\end{pmatrix} : n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z} \} $. As $G$ is a set of discrete points in $GL(2, \mathbb{C} )$, can it be not closed?

In another way, set $G_1 = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\ 
 0 & a 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 b & 0 \\ 
 0 & -b 
\end{pmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{C}^* \} $ and $G_2 = \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\ 
 0 & a 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 b & b \\ 
 0 & -b 
\end{pmatrix} : a,b \in \mathbb{C}^* \}$. They are closed and non-irreducible. And the subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{C})$ generated by $G_1$ and $G_2$ is $G= \{ \begin{pmatrix}
 a & 0 \\ 
 0 & a 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 b & 0 \\ 
 0 & -b 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 c & c \\ 
 0 & -c 
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 d & d \\ 
 0 & d 
\end{pmatrix} : a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}^* \} $. Isn't it closed? And why?

I don't know if I am wrong somewhere.

To prove a variety is closed, we often make the target variety into the inverse image of a closed variety.

But how to prove a variety is not closed (in a certain larger one)?

Many thanks.

Comment: Since you tagged this question as being related to algebraic groups I might guess that you are supposed to use the Zariski topology as opposed to the usual topology.

Comment: Yes, the groups are given the Zariski topology. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are supposed to use Zariski topology, then let's consider the ideal $I(G)$ of polynomials in $R=\mathbf{C}[x_{11},x_{12},x_{21},x_{22}]$ that vanish at all points of $G$. Clearly $x_{11}-1,x_{21},x_{22}^2-1\in I(G)$. Let $J$ be the ideal generated by these three polynomials. We shall prove that actually $J=I(G)$. As the generators of $J$ belong to $I(G)$, clearly $J\subseteq I(G)$. The reverse inclusion
requires a little bit of work.

Let $q$ be an arbitrary polynomial in $I(G)$. The argument is based on the observation that
we can write $q$ in the form $q=p+j$, where $j\in J$, and the other polynomial is of the form $p=f(x_{12})+x_{22}g(x_{12})$, with $f,g\in\mathbf{C}[x_{12}]$. This follows from the facts that

1. For all positive integers $k$ the power $x_{11}^k\equiv 1\pmod J$, because the polynomial $x_{11}-1\in J$,
2. Any multiple of $x_{21}$ is in $J$, because $x_{21}\in J$,
3. For all positive integers $k$ the power $x_{22}^{k+2}\equiv x_{22}^k\pmod J$, because
   the polynomial $x_{22}^2-1\in J$. Applying this recursively we can replace a term with a high power of $x_{22}$ with another one, where the exponent is either zero or one. All this by moving within a single coset of $J$.

We have
$$
p\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&n\\0&1\end{array}\right)=f(n)+g(n),
$$
and
$$
p\left(\begin{array}{cr}1&n\\0&-1\end{array}\right)=f(n)-g(n).
$$
In order for both of these to vanish simultaneously we must have $f(n)=g(n)=0$. This
must happen for all $n\in\mathbf{Z}$. This is possible if and only if $f=g=0$, because a non-zero polynomial has only finitely many zeros in $\mathbf{C}$. Therefore we must actually have $p=0$, so $q\in J$, and $I(G)=J$.

Thus the Zariski closure of $G$ consists of the zero set of polynomials in $J$, but this set 
$$
V(I(G))=V(J)=\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cr}1&z\\0&\pm1\end{array}\right)\mid z\in\mathbf{C}\right\}
$$
is larger than $G$.

Comment: $G \subsetneqq \mathscr{V}(\mathscr{I}(G))$, so $G$ is not closed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sincere thanks to you. I am sorry I wasn't careful enough when I read your answer. In fact there are still some points unclear to me. I think what has to be proved is $G\subsetneq \mathscr{V}(I)$, where $I=\mathscr{I}(G)$. Now what I have seen are $J\subseteq I$, and $G \subsetneq \mathscr{V}(J)$. But if I am not mistaken, when $J \subseteq I$, we have $\mathscr{V}(J) \supseteq \mathscr{V}(I)$. So, I cannot see $G \subsetneq \mathscr{V}(I)$ from $G\subsetneq \mathscr{V}(J)$ which contains $\mathscr{V}(I)$. I hope you will see this comment although this question is so old...

Comment: Is it true that $J$ in fact equals $I$?

Comment: @ShinyaSakai: The first point of my answer was that there cannot be a polynomial $p$ that is in $I(G)$, but is outside of $J$, so $J=I(G)$. The second point was that $V(J)=V(I(G))$ has $G$ as a strict subset. Therefore $G$ is not closed. BTW, the system will ping me automatically. If I hadn't been on-line, I would have seen your comment next time I log on. It's quite efficient :-)

Comment: Thanks to the great INBOX! I've always been careless. This time, let me check your answer CAREFULLY to see if I have understood every point before I thank you one more time.

Comment: @ShinyaSakai: I added more details. Is it clear now?

Comment: Completely clear! In fact, I was just thinking of the "coset" when I saw your new details. Greatly helpful! Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW. While a nice gesture, using a bounty was perhaps a bit overkill. Really, just asking a question or two about details works fine. It is also very much OK to also remove the 'accepted' checkmark and edit the question requesting more details. That will bump your question, and may attract more detailed answers from all and sundry. In that case it is polite (but not necessary) to ping the author of the accepted answer - exactly what you did!! I don't know, if it is possible to retract the bounty. If you are happy with the answer now, I would not mind a moderator doing that for you. No biggie!

Comment: Thank you for all the instructions. I am sorry I don't know much about how to use this forum. But I am really very very glad to give my bounty, although very little, to someone who has been so helpful and given me so enlightenling and detailed answer. So, NO RETRACTION please. Thanks again.