# The subgroup of an algbraic group generated by two non-irreductible closed subsets need not to be closed

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Actually I have difficulties with the Section 7 Exercise 10 of the book J. E. Humphrey "Linear algebraic groups".

This exercises is about what is mentionned in the title. We have to make a demonstration by example and the book alrady gave one:
Consider in $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ the subgroup $H$ generated by the elements
$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)$
and
$\left( \begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 1 \\
 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)$

In addition, I would like to find its Zariski closure $\overline{H}$ and I don't know how to.

Thank you in advance for any hint to solve this.
K. Y.

Comment: In a metric space $X$, a subset $S$ of $X$ is closed if and only if $\lim x_n \in S$ for every **convergent** sequence $\{x_n\}\subseteq S$. You've taken a divergent sequence so you can't conclude anything.

Comment: @rldias Yes, you're right. I had some doubt about it. So it is not the best argument for showing that it is not closed. Unfortunatly, I didn't manage to find another sequence. Could you help me for this?

Comment: In general, to find the Zariski closure of a set $A$, one needs to first find the algebraic equations $f$ for which $f(A)=0$. Then take all the points that satisfy all the equations. This will be the Zariski closure of $A$

Comment: Looks like this is more or less an exact duplicate of [this oldie](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51259/11619). As I answered that one I should not  cast the first vote to close as a dupe though. Also, I endorse Clément's more general argument/hint (+1).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for your answer. I did a research before asking my question but I kind of missed this topic.
In addition to what you said, Since $\overline{H}=V(I(H))$. Indeed, we know that $H \subset \overline{H}$ then $I(\overline{H}) \subset I(H)$ then $V(I(H)) \subset V(I(\overline{H})) = \overline{H}$. And since $V(I(H))$ is a closed set that contains $H$, we have equality. A I right?

Answer (score 2):

First hint: Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, then if $G$ is both countable and Zariski closed, it is finite. Use this to deal with the exercise.

Second hint: Show that the kernel of the determinant map restricted to $H$ is of index $2$ in $H$ and explicitly compute its kernel. Deduce from this the connected component of the Zariski closure of $H$  and then $\overline{H}$.